# piglatin in ruby returning nothing

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, block, apache-pig

I am working on a function that translates sentences to pig latin, however when I give the input as something like "cherry", which should give "errychay", it will give "erryay", ONLY if I return newWord + block + 'ay', if I just put it, I will get an array of empty values.

words that start with a vowel work fine obviously (E.G. apple)

```
def translate(s)
v = %w{a e i o u}
s = s.split.map! do |word|
    if v.include? word[0]
        word + 'ay' 
    else
        for letter in 0...word.length 
            block = ''
            if !(v.include? word[letter] )
                block += word[letter]
            else
                newWord = word.slice(letter,word.length - 1)
                newWord + block + 'ay' 
                block = ''
                break
            end
        end
    end
end
s.join(' ')
```

end

Comment: UPDATE: One mistake fixed, silly mistake of putting block = '' at beginning of loop -_-', now I just need to know why its not returning unless I put return in front of the concatonation.

Comment: who uses the `for` keyword in ruby anyway?  :P  `0.upto(word.length-1) do |letter|` imo ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 things, the one you identified which is the block = '' needs to happen outside the loop.  The other two are:

```
else
  newWord = word.slice(letter,word.length - 1)
  newWord + block + 'ay'                       # this does nothing
  block = ''
  break                                        # nothing makes it back to map
end
```

I assume you meant for `newWord + block + 'ay'` to be the value returned for the `map` call, it's not.  Try this:

```
def translate(s)
  v = %w{a e i o u}
  s = s.split.map! do |word|
    if v.include? word[0]
      word + 'ay' 
    else
      block = ''
      for letter in 0...word.length 
        if !(v.include? word[letter] )
          block += word[letter]
        else
          newWord = word.slice(letter,word.length - 1)
          newWord += block + 'ay' 
          block = ''
          break(newWord)
        end
      end
    end
  end
  s.join(' ')
end

p translate('apple')
p translate('cherry')
p translate('fancy')
```

Running it:

```
(nick@thin)-(~)
(508)⚡️ ruby Desktop/test.rb 
"appleay"
"errychay"
"ancyfay"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `block = ''` happens at the beginning of every iteration of your `for` loop. So, block keeps getting reset to `''`, resulting in `newWord + '' + 'ay'` which is what you're getting. You can fix this by pulling out the `block = ''` so that it only happens one time, *before* your `for` loop:

```
def translate(s)
  v = %w{a e i o u}
  s = s.split.map! do |word|
    if v.include? word[0]
      word + 'ay' 
    else
      block = ''
      for letter in 0...word.length 
        if !(v.include? word[letter] )
          block += word[letter]
        else
          newWord = word.slice(letter,word.length - 1)
          break (newWord + block + 'ay')
        end
      end
    end
  end
  s.join(' ')
end
```

EDIT: I couldn't resist refactoring your code a little. I mainly wanted to present a way of doing this that doesn't involve manually `break`ing out of the loop. The trick is to define small, helper functions.

```
def vowel?(letter)
  %w{a e i o u}.include? letter
end

def translate(word)
  if vowel? word[0]
    word + 'ay' 
  else
    head = ''
    for i in 0...word.length 
      unless vowel? word[i]
        head += word[i]
      else
        tail = word.slice(i, word.length - 1)
        return tail + head + 'ay'
      end
    end
  end
end

def translate_sentence(s)
  s.split.map {|word| translate word}.join(' ')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate approach although you still need to find a way to handle blends like ('ch','th',etc.)

```
 def to_pig_latin(sentence)
   v = %w(a e i o u)
   sentence.split.map{|word| v.include?(word[0].downcase) ? word << 'ay' : word[1..-1] << word[0] << 'ay'}.join(' ')
 end
```